# How to delete a TableRow in JavaFx

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tableview

How can I add some action to a JavaFx Button in a TableView Row so that that particular TableRow and the corresponding database table that populates the particular Row gets deleted when the button is pressed?

Each Row on the TableView will have it's own delete Button.

This what I have so far:

```
KiwiAction.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object>("KiwiAction"));
KiwiAction.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object>, TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object> call(TableColumn<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object> param) {
        final Button button;
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/MediaTools/Error.png"));
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitHeight(16);
        imageView.setFitWidth(16);

        imageView.setImage(image);

        button = new Button("", imageView);
        final TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object> cell = new TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    final VBox vbox = new VBox(0);

                    button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    button.maxWidth(32);
                    button.getStyleClass().add("deleteButton");

                    final TableCell<NewBeautifulKiwi, Object> c = this;

                    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                            TableRow tableRow = c.getTableRow();
                            NewBeautifulKiwi item = (NewBeautifulKiwi) tableRow.getTableView().getItems().get(tableRow.getIndex());

                            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                            session.beginTransaction();

                            NewBeautifulKiwi toDelete = (NewBeautifulKiwi) session.get(NewBeautifulKiwi.class, item);
                            session.delete(toDelete);
                            session.getTransaction().commit();
                            session.flush();
                            session.close();
                            System.out.println("Deleted");
                        }
                    });
                    vbox.getChildren().add(button);
                    setGraphic(vbox);
                }

            }
        };
        cell.setGraphic(button);
        return cell;
    }
});

Kiwi.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NewBeautifulKiwi, String>("Kiwi"));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Been at this for the last two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way to do it is to remove the item from the `ObservableList` or clear the `ObservableList` and repopulate it, then assign this list to the table again !

This will work out !

-Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for the response [@ItachiUchiha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759128/itachiuchiha). Would you mind showing a hint on how to implement that? What I have above doesn't do anything on button click. Nothing at all. The action doesn't register in any way. No errors even.

Comment: You can follow line 332 from https://github.com/friends-repository/QuotationFX/blob/master/Quotations/src/com/kc/controller/PriceEstimationViewController.java

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that.